# Why is it saying Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\Controller, because the name is already in use in?

Tags: laravel

```
     [![This is the error][1]][1]
```

This is the Controller.php but i think this is a built in when creating a laravel project.

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
    
    class Controller extends BaseController
    {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    }
```

Comment: do you use any class named controller ?

Comment: i might have done that when i created a controller but i already deleted it

Comment: well, try to autload composer, and check if you have any model called Controller

Comment: will try thank you

Comment: saly it doesnt fix it

Comment: try running ```php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear``` for good measure, especially if you've changed that base class